# Image doesn't turn invisible

Tags: android, kotlin

I made 2 ImageViews on top of each other. I want to toggle the image on top visible and invisible when I click on the checkbox. But it doesn't turn back into invisible once it became visible. I tried to use View.GONE too, but then it dissappears without getting back to visible.

Here my Code

```
    val btn_click_me = findViewById(R.id.checkBox) as Button
    btn_click_me.setOnClickListener {
        val imageon = findViewById(R.id.imageViewOn) as ImageView
        if(imageon.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
            imageon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
        }
        if(imageon.visibility == View.INVISIBLE){
            imageon.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
```

my xml code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewOff"
    android:layout_width="37dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/haltestelleoff" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewOn"
    android:layout_width="37dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/haltestelleon" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/imageViewOff"
    android:text="" />
```

my xml layout is Relative Layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the condition.It should be `if else` and not `if if` condition.

```
  if(imageon.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
        imageon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
    }else {
        imageon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that I overrode it all the time

Comment: This implies the view can either vi VISIBLE or INVISIBLE. It could also be GONE, so the OP should be aware of this and whether this state should be checked or not, perhaps it's not even used in the app so this would be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

look at here :

```
if(imageon.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
        imageon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
}
if(imageon.visibility == View.INVISIBLE){
        imageon.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

Here first you make it invisible and in the second if you check and make it visible again !
change it to `if else`

Comment: Thank you, I didnt realize that my Ifs are cancelling the first one.